# How to play Gif file on png file?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, animated-gif

```
Stack([
Image.asset(
    "assets/Icon/Checkbox.png",
    color: uncheckedColor,
    height: 22,
    width: 22,
    ),
Image.asset(
    "assets/Icon/fullyComplete1.gif",
    color: uncheckedColor,
    scale: 2.5,
    opacity: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<double>(1.0),
    height: 22,
    width: 22,
    gaplessPlayback: true,
  )
])
```

I want play GIF file for 1 or 2 seconds then I have to show png file.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You can use Timer with initState to wait about 2 seconds.

Comment: How? Can you explain it briefly?

Comment: check @u0j 's answer, that should probably do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can, this  solution is simple :

Add new variable in top class `var show = false;`

after that's add this function :

```
  @override
  void initState() {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
         setState(() => show = true);
   });
   super.initState();
  }
```

**Now add this your code**

```
    Stack([
show ? Image.asset(
    "assets/Icon/Checkbox.png",
    color: uncheckedColor,
    height: 22,
    width: 22,
    ) :
   Image.asset(
    "assets/Icon/fullyComplete1.gif",
    color: uncheckedColor,
    scale: 2.5,
    opacity: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<double>(1.0),
    height: 22,
    width: 22,
    gaplessPlayback: true,
        )
     ])
```